# VBA Methods Replaced by Variable

Tags: vba

I'm still a VBA novice, but I'm starting to get a better handle on things. Though I made the dumb mistake of declaring a variable that's the same as a method. I declared the variable: `Dim cellS As Range`

But then it replaced all the instances of the method `Cells.` in my code returning an error. So I changed my variable name to `Scell` and replaced all instances of it in my code with the new name. But the method still continued to change to `cellS` rather than staying `Cells.`.

I even tried deleting that variable and all instances of it in my code. No change. Then I removed all instances of the text "cells" in my code but it still keeps replacing the method with `cellS`.

I'm not sure where it's still pulling it from. I tried bringing the code into a new module, but that yielded no change.

Any assistance is appreciated. I use the `Cells.` method quite a bit in my code, but until this is resolved it won't run...

Thanks!

Comment: If you have successfully changed the variable name to avoid clashes with built in functions then you may want to simply save your code then close and reopen Excel.

Comment: Pro tip: use a versioning system, like git(hub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried restarting my computer. Still does the same thing. I even tried saving the excel file under a new name. That didn't change anything.

Thankfully I have my files saved in a OneDrive location so I was able to download a previous version of the file. Then I copied my new code over to the downloaded file and it behaved.